# Update prop property when vuex store changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

After a successful mutation to the vuex store (`state.posts.post.comments`) using this code, and using `Vue.set` so Vue can recognize the addition of an object property:

**store/modules/post.js**

```
const mutations = {
    [types.SET_POST_COMMENTS] (state, { comments, id }) {
      let post = state.posts.find(post => post._id === id)
      Vue.set(post, 'comments', comments)
    }
}
```

There is no update to the template or component. The prop `post` is non-reactive (I assume because even the watcher isn't triggered). I've double checked and the Vuex store for each post's comments property is successfully being updated with a comments object, but the component `SinglePost.vue` doesn't see these changes.

**SinglePost.vue**

```
export default {
  name: 'single-post',
  props: {
    'post': {
      type: Object
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      currPost: this.post // tried to reassign post locally
    }
  },
  computed: {
    comments() {
      return this.post.comments // tried to compute comments locally
    }
  },
  watch: {
    post: function(val) { // tried to watch currPost for changes
       console.log('never triggered')
       this.currPost = val 
    }
  }
```

Ultimately, I can just set a local var by explicitly returning comments from the store to a component method and setting a local comments object, but I want to use my central store (and assume there'd be a way).

**SinglePost template**

```
{{comments}} // always empty
{{post}} // doesn't reflect store Vue.set for post.comments
{{currPost}} // doesn't reflect store Vue.set for post.comments
```

**Edit**

How I'm getting posts is:

```
getPosts ({ commit, state, getters, dispatch, rootState }, ctx) {
  //other stuff
  APIHelper.post('/post/search', mergedPayload).then(res => {
    var results = res.data.results
    commit('SET_POSTS', posts || [])
    // where SET_POSTS is just state.posts = posts
```

the vuex action `getPosts` is called from `Posts.vue` component without returning anything since it's set by a mutation `@click="getPosts(this.context)"` (this works great for setting the posts)

```
    <div v-for="post in posts">
      <single-post :key="post._id" :post="post" context="feed" />
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you show how you're retrieving the `post` object from the store and passing it to the component as the prop?

Comment: @thanksd, i updated my post with an "Edit" -- basically posts (contains many post objects) are set on the store, iterated over with `v-for` in `Posts.vue` where each `post` is passed as a prop to `SinglePost.vue` (i've gotten it to work by retrieving and setting comments in SinglePost, but not using the vuex store)

Comment: In that `v-for`, where / how is the data for `posts` being set?

Comment: @thanksd, it's set in the `SET_POSTS` mutation in the vuex store with `state.posts = payload` called from the `getPosts` action. The `getPosts` action is dispatched by the action handler `getPosts` attached to a click event (`@click="getPosts(this.context)"`) in Posts.vue — in brief, `posts` is set in the vuex store, not in the component

Comment: I mean how are you accessing the value of those `posts` from your component? Do you have a `getter` set up? Are you using `mapGetters`?

Comment: @thanksd, ahh sorry... yes, I'm using `mapGetters`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use vuex's `mapGetters` [helper method](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getters.html).

```
computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
        currPost: 'GET_CURRENT_POST'
    })
},
```

It gives access to store state and is reactive so you won't need watchers or additional computeds.

Comment: I added a getter `postById: state => (postId) => _.find(state.posts, ['_id', postId]),` and passed in a postId to test your theory, but it's still not updating. I would also expect a getter not to cache when the store changes, but that should also be true of the `computed: { comments()` I used in my post. I.e., if computed isn't working, getters prob wouldn't either, right?

Comment: mapGetters is a bit of a misnomer. Notice the helper is used within the `computed` declaration, ergo it's actually creating computed properties. He is right though, set correctly and the vuex store is a global reactive object is the broadest sense.

Comment: hmm, I guess when trying to map a getter to the `post` object itself it didn't work, but when mapping it to a new object and using that instead `currPost` it does work. So @Ashram you were right all along. My apologies

Answer (score 0):

Two-way data binding is a great way to achieve this, you can create your own getter/setter method and import it in your Vue components whenever you need it:

```
export function mapFields(fields)
{
    let computers = {}
    for (let field of fields) {
        computers[field] = {
            get() {
                return this.$store.state[field];
            },
            set(value) {
                this.$store.commit(`UPDATE_${field.toUpperCase()}`, value);
            }
        }
    }
    return computers;
}
```

Then in your Vue component:

```
import {mapFields} from 'utils.js'; // or whatever the name of the file

computed: {
   ...mapFields(['mappedState']),
},
```

Updating this.mappedState in your Vue component:

```
this.mappedState = ['foo', 'bar'];
```

will trigger:

```
this.$store.commit('UPDATE_MAPPEDSTATE', ['foo', 'bar']);
```

And to get the property's data just call it in your component:

```
// In your template
{{ mappedState }}

// In Vue methods
this.mappedState;
```